# How to prevent "framing"?

Tags: iframe

My website keeps getting hijacked by searchportal.information it looks like they are using an iframe script to do it. [here is the script](http://searchportal.information.com/?a_id=47368&domainname=www.%28mysite%29.com) (link doesn't work anymore):

how do I prevent them from including my site/content on an iframe on their site?

Answer (score 7):

Use a frame breaker script:

```
<script type="javascript">
        if(location.href!=top.location.href){ 

            top.location.href=location.href
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the best ways to prevent framing, is to use a rule on your .htaccess, like so

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

This method doesn't rely on JavaScrpit being active or not but on the [support of the X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options). It is not an [Internet Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034), but it is quite well supported as of February 2014